# Taking Students details and displaying it

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I am new to java and need help in this assignment.
It is showing me error arrayindexoutofbound.

I tried changing it without using object but it is then showing errors too

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Result {

    int  n;
    int [] rollno = new int[n];
    int [] marks = new int[n];
    String [] name = new String[n];

    Result()
    {
        rollno[n] = 0;
        marks[n] = 0;
        name [n] = "NA";

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Result BSCS = new Result();

        System.out.println("ENter number of students ");
        BSCS.n = cin.nextInt();

        for(int i =1; i<=BSCS.n; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter Name of " + i + " student");
        BSCS.name[i] = cin.next();

        System.out.println("Enter RollNO of " + i + " student");
        BSCS.rollno[i] = cin.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Marks of " + i + " student");
        BSCS.marks[i] = cin.nextInt();
        }


        System.out.println("|No\t|Name\t|RollNo\t|Marks ");
        for(int j =1; j<=BSCS.n; j++)
        {

            System.out.println("|" + j + "\t|" + BSCS.name[j] + "\t|" + BSCS.rollno[j] + "\t|" + BSCS.marks[j]);

        }   
    } 
}
```

It is showing the following error:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Result.<init>(Result.java:15) at Result.main(Result.java:35)`

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `new int[n]` when you didn't bother to initialize `n` to a value? It obviously only will get the default value 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize the `n` variable to a specific number (since you are using arrays and not a list), e.g:

```
// create records for 10! students
int  n = 11;
```

And then in your constructor change `n` to `n-1`:

```
Result()
{
    rollno[n-1] = 0;
    marks[n-1] = 0;
    name [n-1] = "NA";

}
```

**Explanation:**

When you do not initialize the `n` at the start, `n = 0`. That means you are trying to create an array of length zero, e.g. `int [] rollno = new int[0];`. This is fine, until you try to set an array value to zero in your constructor - you get error because you cannot access any value of an *empty* array - `rollno[0] = 0` means to set the *first* array cell to 0, but your array is empty!

Next, you are thinking that with `BSCS.n = cin.nextInt();` you will be able to set the value of `n` and set the number of students. Sure, but with `Main BSCS = new Main();` line that was before you have already created the rollno, marks and name array of size 0. Therefore, `BSCS.n = cin.nextInt();` literally does nothing in terms of setting the sizes of rollno, marks and name arrays. So if `n` is not set at the beginning, all your arrays are still empty.

By initializing `n` in the beginning, you can create the arrays rollno, marks and name with appropriate size. You must use `n-1`, since we start counting from zero and `rollno[10]`, for example, would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start  at 0 and go untill `lenght-1` ?

```java
for(int i = 0; i < BSCS.n; i++)
```